# jQuery/javascript "rotate" effect for image swap upon change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-effects

I'm looking for an image transition similar to the rotate effect in WOW Slider: http://wowslider.com/javascript-slideshow-quiet-rotate-demo.html

The main difference is I want the transition to happen upon the change event of a dropdown.  Here's the functional code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zCknb/14/

The js is straightforward enough:

```
$("#assignee").change(function () {
   $("#pic").attr("src", $("#assignee").val());
})
```

If I change the Assignee, I'd like the new photo to swirl in like the rotate effect in the WOW Slider.

I don't want to deconstruct an entire slider library if I can help it. Does someone know of a simpler way to get this effect?

**EDIT:** I thank everyone for their input so far, but I'm looking for an effect that's equivalent to the rotate in WOW Slider. Simple slides aren't going to cut it.

Comment: Did you achieved this ? I need same functionality

Answer (score 0):

coin slider jquery plugin has swirl effect. check this if its helpful http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/245/Coin-Slider-Image-Slider-with-Unique-EffectsjQuery and you can use on change event handler of jquery

Comment: How would you change its behavior to swap images on the dropdpwn change event? Plus, this effect doesn't actually rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. see: http://jsfiddle.net/zCknb/12/

effects:

```
/*
* effects
* animate-left_goright           
* animate-right_goleft           
* animate-top_gobottom
* animate-bottom_gotop
*/
```

option attr **animate="animate-left_goright"**

- create left after animate left ++;

option attr **animate="animate-right_goleft"**

- create right after left animate ++;

option attr **animate="animate-top_gobottom"**

- create -top after bottom animate ++;

option attr **animate="animate-bottom_gotop"**

- create -bottom after top animate ++;

> Review and understand this example.

take is easy;

Comment: Hi Yasar, this doesn't perform similarly to the rotate effect in WOW Slider. My end user is requiring a similar transition.